# string,print, {segmentation fault (core dumped)}

Tags: c

I would like to know how I can refer to a specific letter of my string word 
for example `word[1]` and how I can print a string. Obviously this is wrong:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
        char *word;
        printf("give us the word you want to play with\n");
        scanf("%s", word);
        printf("%s\n", word[1]);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: use `%c` instead of `%s`?

Comment: @RNar Wouldn't fix the use of an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: It's absolutely unclear what you are asking for. I think it would be better if you add some words that help understanding your actual problem/goal.

Comment: Why are you using C? Isn't there another language you are familiar with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word is a pointer to an unkown location,which will result in it being filled with random values and will cause a seg fault.to fix this change`char *word` to `char *word = malloc(1024)` you can change 1024 to any integer you think is suitable.Your next issue is that you are trying to print a char using `%s`,just change it to `%c` and you'll be good.Additionally you may want to add free to the end,if you want to free that memory.
Here's some example code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
      char *word = malloc(256);
      printf("Enter a word:")
      scanf("%s",word);
      printf("%c",word[0]);
      free(word);
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: when i run this :
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
      char *word = malloc(256);
      printf("Enter a word:")
      scanf("%s",word);
      printf("%c",word[0]);
      return 0;
}
i cant compile cause
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’

Comment: It's not very helpful to suggest `malloc` without suggesting `free` at the same time. Why use `malloc` at all? -- it's not better than `char word[256]`.

Comment: @ceidASS add #include <stdlib.h> I forgot to include that sorry

Comment: @Wolf Sorry i'm used to using my c library I wrote for my OS and i'm too lazy to implement free,so I've kind of forgoten about it.

Answer (score 0):

`word` is a uninitialized pointer. You can't read into the memory it's point to. Your code has [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to allocate memory, for example:

```
    char *word = malloc(256); //arbitrary number of bytes
```

Or use an array `char word[256];`.

To print a *string* ( a C-string is a sequence of bytes with a nul '\0' terminator), you would use:

```
    printf("%s \n",word);
```

If you just want to print only a char then you need to use the correct format specifier for printing a single character, which is `%c`:

```
    printf("%c \n",word[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`word` is uninitialized, and points to somewhere unknown.  Then you write a string to that unknown place.  This won't end well.

Instead, give `word` some space:

```
char word[100];
```

Then, to print out a specific character, ask `printf()` to do just that. `%s` prints a string; characters make lousy string pointers.

```
printf("%c \n", word[1]);
```